How to find values then review and get replaced with changes from VBA
Reference

Been working to search list of values and through multiple sheets and replace with review and changes, find the image attached for reference.
tried with Find and replace, but not able to satisfy the requirement,
able to replace only single value at a time.

Initially need to search for available matches through multiple sheets

Then print found values in specified range(Review_area - (Refer image))

After changes made in Review area need to check every iterations is replaced or not

then replace the changes and notify with message box
Option Explicit

Sub Find_Replace_01()

'PURPOSE: Find & Replace text/values throughout entire workbook, notify user of how many cells were affected


Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
Dim ReplaceCount As Long

fnd = InputBox("Find", "Find")
rplc = InputBox("Replace", "Replace")

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


  ReplaceCount = ReplaceCount + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sht.Cells, "*" & fnd & "*")


  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next sht

MsgBox "I have completed my search and made replacements in " & ReplaceCount & " cell(s)."


End Sub




Are the values to replace are in Column A? If yes, then make another column beside it with the replacement values. Loop through the table rows with your for each code.

Your posted code doesn't seem related to the steps you want to carry out?  Also uses "*" & fnd & "*" for the CountIf but LookAt:=xlWhole for the Replace so the count may be higher than the number of replacements.

What's the purpose of the first column on the screenshot?

You need to add more details or no-one can really help with this....
